# how to bypass TouchExplorationMode in AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

Been stuck on this for a while now...

I have an `AccessibilityService` which I'm using to read the screens content. Some of this content is hidden as its in a `ListView`. I can see the content if I enable TouchExplorationMode on the `AccessibilityService` and touch the item in the listView.

However if this is enabled all single touch gestures are picked up as hover gestures. I have found that you can't enable and disable this option programmatically. Is there a way of converting the hover event back into a touch event ?

I've found this [converting hover to touch using Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702703/talkback-handling-single-finger-touch-events-how-to-avoid-delay). However I require the same thing but from an `AccessibilityService` which has no view.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, did u get the solution for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly pass hover events through to the application window with TouchExplorationMode on.  It is not possible.  However, what makes you think you can't enable and disable TouchExplorationMode programmatically???  This would be false.  Here's how you do it.

```
public class YourA11yService extends AccessibilityService {

    private void enableTouchExploration() {
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = mInstance.getServiceInfo();

        info.flags |= AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_MODE;

        mInstance.setServiceInfo(info);
    }

    private void disableTouchExploration() {
        AccessibilityServiceInfo serviceInfo = mInstance.getServiceInfo();

        serviceInfo.flags &= ~AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_MODE;

        mInstance.setServiceInfo(serviceInfo);
    }

}
```

Although, you don't need touch exploration mode on to find this content.  Just find the list view within the current window content.  Why do you have to touch it to have access to it?

EDIT: 
AndroidManifest.xml

```
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".A11yService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/service_config" />

    <
    ...
```

ServiceConfig.xml (R.xml.service_config)

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...
   android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
   android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
   .../>
```

Note: I have removed a lot of the scaffolding, and other essential properties, to boil it down tot he minimum settings you need to get this working.  Obviously there are other essential aspects of these files!

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the suggestion but it won't work. 
Setting this flag without it being set in the meta-data doesn't work for "API version higher than JELLY_BEAN_MR1 "
see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html#FLAG_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_MODE

Also, You can't see ALL information on the screen from an accessibility service. an example of this is listview elements - you can hide this I can't find a link for this at the moment but I'm sure that you can hide certain elements (???)

Comment: If you can't maybe its how I'm viewing the UI - I do it by printing out all the sourcenodes and their children if they have them. Using this method it gets to listview but doesn't go further

Comment: Updated my anser for you missing elements issue, you want to include the flag "flagIncludeNotIMportantViews" either in code or in your xml.  As for the JEELY_BEAN_MR1, you're misunderstanding.  You can still apply the flag dynamically.  There is no difference between XML configuration, and code.  If you look into the AOSP code, the xml config just reads the service configuration, and applies the line of code that I have provided.  So LITERALLY identical.  What you DO need however, is a line in your manifest/service configuration to allow that flag.  I have added this to the answer as well.